Why QPixmap looks ugly on laptop when DPI is set to 125%
I'm trying to draw a png image (using QPixmap) in a QLabel with Qt6. I resize the pixmap to fit the QLabel size. It looks just fine when DPI is set to 100%. But on my laptop, where DPI is set to 125% (to make text bigger, this is the default recommended config on the laptop), the pixmap looks ugly (the lines are blured):

In comparison, I set the same png image as icon to a QPushButton and it looks just fine.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How can the code be fixed to make the image look as nice as in the QPushButton?
Here is the full code:
mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget* parent ) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    centralWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget));

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
    button->setIcon(QIcon(":/qtbug_pixmapscale/image.png"));

    QWidget* labelsWidget = new QWidget(centralWidget);
    labelsWidget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout(labelsWidget));

    QLabel* titleLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    titleLabel->setText("This is ugly:");

    QLabel* iconLabel = new QLabel(centralWidget);
    int maxHeight = titleLabel->sizeHint().height() + 10;
    iconLabel->setMaximumSize( QSize(maxHeight,maxHeight) );
    iconLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/qtbug_pixmapscale/image.png").scaled(iconLabel->maximumSize(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
    
    labelsWidget->layout()->addWidget(titleLabel);
    labelsWidget->layout()->addWidget(iconLabel);

    centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(button);
    centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(labelsWidget);

    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
}

main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

// Qtbug where QPixmap drawn in a QLabel looks ugly on laptop when display is set to 125%

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow wnd; 
    wnd.show();

    return app.exec();
}

mainwindow.h:
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = NULL);

};

pixmapscale.qrc:

    
        image.png
    

image.png: 

Does this answer your question? What is the best way to scale images for high DPI in Qt5?

@musicamante: I believe it does not. It explains how to get the good size for images considering DPI setting. It does not fix the ugly display I get.

The point of linking that post is that you must get the the pixmap based on the real pixel ratio, you cannot just use the size hint of the label. In fact, that's exactly what the QIcon::pixmap() does (as explained in the docs): when font scaling is active, you must compute the correct pixel ratio based and either set it for the pixmap or consider the scaling for the pixmap size with setDevicePixelRatio().

@musicamante: Could you please send this with appropriate code as an answer?

Unfortunately no, as I don't use font scaling, I'm not on Windows and I don't even write in C++ (I use PyQt). The linked answer and related docs should be enough for you, though. Just ensure that you check the DPI-aware docs in Qt, including the parts related to paint devices (remember that both QWidget and QPixmap are paint devices).

@musicamante, could test it and you was write, it works. Just posted an answer myself. Thank you for your help!

As proposed by musicamante, using QPixmap::setDevicePixelRatio solves the problem:
auto pixmap = QPixmap(":/qtbug_pixmapscale/image.png").scaled(iconLabel->maximumSize(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
pixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(qApp->primaryScreen()->devicePixelRatio());
iconLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);


As QIcon set to QPushButton looks good, I just found a workaround:
iconLabel->setPixmap(QIcon(":/qtbug_pixmapscale/image.png").pixmap(iconLabel->size()));

It looks better, as QIcon class apparently handles DPI factor smartly.

